# zend framework 2 routing configurations and parameters passing

Tags: zend-framework2

I've started a zend2 project and I can't figure out the routing system. I really need some help passing some variables from a view back to the controller. The module configuration looks as it follows:

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Map\Controller\Index' => 'Map\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'map' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route'    => '/map[/:action][/:tileId]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                    // the controllers for your module are found
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Map\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                // specific routes.
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'map' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
);
```

I have a method 2 methods in my controller where I want to pass parameters:

```
public function buyTileAction($tileId){
    echo $tileId; 
}
```

and a similar one, the problem is that I try "myappname.dev/map/buy-tile" and it enters the method and prints a string only for example, but when I try to pass a parameter like "myappname.dev/map/buy-tile/tileId/1" I don't receive the value in the controller.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$tileId = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('tileId');
```

Comment: Hello, tried both solutions(@Adam H's and @KeyneON's), none gives me the expected result. instead of printing the value of the variable, the request gives a "The requested URL could not be matched by routing." when i try to access myappname.dev/map/buy-tile/tileId/1 ,anyone has any other idea on how to fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need to do.

```
public function buyTileAction() {
    $tileId = $this->params()->fromRoute('tileId');
}
```